# ODBC - overflow

Tags: c#, oracle, odbc

I've an ODBC connection to reach an Oracle database, the connection does Open(). I get an overflow error when i try to access to data in the DB.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MySelectString = "SELECT * FROM QE_AGENT.IMP_BANK WHERE BANK_LOT = '13120314' AND BANK_COMPTE = '1021'";
        string MyConnString = "info de connexion";

        OdbcConnection MyConnec = new OdbcConnection(MyConnString);

        MyConnec.Open();
        OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(MySelectString, MyConnec);
        DataSet MyDataSet = new DataSet();

        adapter.Fill(MyDataSet);  <---- i get the error here                   
    }
```

1) As i searched i found out this might be a drvier problem, when i try to connect my DB through graphical interface i can only see my x86 ODBC sources. 
But if i do the connection inside the code it works fine with the x64 source.

2) I've tried with Datareader now i try with DataAdapter+DataSet but i get the same error with both.

3) this SQL query should select only 1 row in my DB, can the problem of overflow be because the connection failed and it return null ?

Any suggestion ?
Thanks

EDIT: Here is the exception's details

> L'exception System.OverflowException s'est produite
>   HResult=0x80131516   Message=L'opération arithmétique a provoqué un
>   dépassement de capacité.   Source=System.Data   Arborescence des
>   appels de procédure :
>
> at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.FirstResult()
>   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior
>   behavior,     String method, Boolean needReader, Object[]
>   methodArguments, SQL_API     odbcApiMethod)
>   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior
>   behavior,     String method, Boolean needReader)
>   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset,
>   DataTable[]     datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords,
>   String srcTable, IDbCommand     command, CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32
>   startRecord,     Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand
>   command, CommandBehavior     behavior)
>   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)
>   at Test.Form1.button4_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Users\sysnt2\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\Test\Test\Form1.cs:line     75
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button,     Int32 clicks)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd,
>   Int32     msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNa>tiveMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop
>   (IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at Test.Program.Main() in
>   C:\Users\sysnt2\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\Test\Test\Program.cs:line 19

Comment: Can you post the error message

Comment: @Izzy i've added the exception's details

Comment: It is a very strange exception, I see no obvious place in the code for FirstResult() where it could be raised.  It may originate from native code in the Oracle data provider, there is an FPU exception that is reported the same way.  You might see more by enabling unmanaged debugging and forcing the debugger to stop on a Win32 Exception.

Comment: @HansPassant its already enabled. I think i'll just search for a x64 .net IDE unless someone find the solution.

Thank you tho !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find out why it didnt work, the person who installed my ODBC driver installed the x86 and named it x64. I had to reinstall everything and now it works perfectly.

Thank you tho :)

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason for your error could be that, One or more columns in your table **QE_AGENT.IMP_BANK** could have an Oracle data with a datatype that is not accommodating in the .Net Dataset.

Comment: In the DB all my columns' type are either char, date or int